# Add ng-model to a dynamic directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to create a dynamic directive in an ng-repeat using this code:

```
app.directive('element', function($compile) {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
        link : function (scope,element,attr)
        {
            attr.$observe('type', function (val) {
                scope.type = val;
              });

              attr.$observe('value', function (val) {
                scope.value = val;
              });

               attr.$observe('name', function (val) {
                scope.name = val;
              });

              scope.$watch(function()
              {

                formFieldTemplate= $('<a>').attr('m',scope.name).attr('class',scope.type).attr('value',scope.value); 
                $compile(formFieldTemplate)(scope); 
                $(element).replaceWith(formFieldTemplate);

              })

        }
    }
    });

supa.directive('Textbox', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link : function (scope,element,attr)
        {
                    formFieldTemplate= $('<input>').attr('type','text').attr("ng-model","mm."+attr.m); 
                    $compile(formFieldTemplate)(scope); 
                    var formListElement = $(element);
                    formListElement.replaceWith(formFieldTemplate);
        }
    }
})
```

This Code display the field right.
but when i put the ng-model in the textbox directive I get an error
`Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`
If I remove the text ng-model everything work fine.
The ng-repeat that is wraping the element tag return me the directive I will use.
I have more directive like textbox, textarea, checkbok and more.

Comment: I'm working on something similar. I got it to work doing things a little differently. In the 'Textbox' settings, try using `{ replace:true, template:'<input ....'>}` instead of doing the work in the linking function.